# 503 Service Unavailable with ambassador QOTM service

Tags: kubernetes, envoyproxy

I have a kubernetes master/node setup in cent os. After setting up ambassador as an API gateway, I have tried a sample route with QOTM service for which when I send a http request to the route, I receive 503 Service unavailable in the response with body as = "no healthy upstream". But the same qotm service when I ran it as a stand alone docker container it worked for the route.
Is there any thing specific to be taken care in kubernetes to setup ambassador.

```
> kubectl exec ambassador-589c864695-cg556 -- curl -v 10.101.64.22/qotm/*
> no healthy upstream*   Trying 10.101.64.22...
> * TCP_NODELAY set
>  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* > Connected to 10.101.64.22 (10.101.64.22) port 80 (#0)
> GET /qotm/* HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.101.64.22
> User-Agent: curl/7.63.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< content-length: 19
< content-type: text/plain
< date: Fri, 22 Mar 2019 03:54:16 GMT
< server: envoy
<
{ [19 bytes data]
100    19  100    19    0     0  19000      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 19000
* Connection #0 to host 10.101.64.22 left intact
```

Comment: ambassador logs shows '3.196][000067][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-dbg/bin/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_mux_subscription_lib/common/config/grpc_mux_subscription_impl.h:70] gRPC config for type.googleapis.com/envoy.api.v2.Listener rejected: Error adding/updating listener ambassador-listener-80: route: unknown weighted cluster 'cluster_qotm'
[2019-03-22 08:42:53.201][000067][warning][config] [b'

Comment: Can you please share your ambassador deployments and services  manifests in order to reproduce the case. thnx

Comment: I ahve analysed it further to find that the DNS 10.96.0.10 is not accessible from the pod hence the service lookup fails. I am now following to understand on how this has to be exposed.

Comment: thnx for followup, any issues with your dns pods? `kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep dns`

Comment: all pods are with status running. no issues. I was wondering if there is any relation between the node ip (which is from a VirtualBox HostOnly n/w) and the pod ip from Flannel??

Comment: Actually have a similar issue, [2019-04-12 03:10:51.323][65][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-dbg/bin/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_mux_subscription_lib/common/config/grpc_mux_subscription_impl.h:77] gRPC config for type.googleapis.com/envoy.api.v2.Listener rejected: Error adding/updating listener(s) ambassador-listener-80: route: unknown weighted cluster 'cluster_httpbin_org_80'
Ambassador v0.53.1. I check the DNS pods they seem to be working fine.

Comment: in my case, I could manage to get it working with WeaveNet as the CNI. Though I could not spent time and analyse the issue faced with flannel. Cheers